# Is there a way to copy a postgres db to heroku?

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I have a django project that I was initially running on pythonanywhere using a postgres database. However, pythonanywhere doesn't support ASGI, so I am migrating the project over to heroku. Since heroku either much prefers or mandates use of its own postgres functionality, I need to migrate the data from elephantsql. However, I'm really coming up short on how... I tried running pg_dumpall but it didn't seem to want to work and/or the file disappeared into the ether. I'm at a loss for how to make this migration... If anyone could help, I'd appreciate it so much. T-T

Comment: not an answer to your question, are you using any chat app in Django project ? if not why do you use ASGI ?

Comment: I am, yes. I'm using django channels.

Comment: try amazon ec2 postgresql, they have good customer support

Comment: You are migrating from PythonAnywhere --> Heroku, not sure how ElephantSQL got in the mix? Also what was the command you ran for pg_dumpall?

Comment: I migrated the code to heroku just fine, my problem is migrating the data from elephantsql to heroku

Answer (score 2):

After hours of searching and doing what I can to scour heroku's listed info, I found it by running `heroku pg:push --help`.

For a locally running server, run
`heroku pg:push '<db_name>' <heroku_db_name> --app <app_name>`

For a hosted one, run
`heroku pg:push <postgres_link> <heroku_db_name> --app <app_name>`